# how to add an additional method to get word count and first word of a string

Tags: java

I'm still fairly new to Java and understanding the basics of everything, we just started talking about methods.

I'm having a hard time implementing this new method.. without using arrays or vectors or anything in the sort..
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
public class ClosedLab07{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
        String str = getInputString(keyboard);
        int count = getWordCount(str);
        System.out.println("Your string has " + (count+1) + " words in it.");
        // Fill in the body with your code
    }

    // Given a Scanner, prompt the user for a String.  If the user enters an empty
    // String, report an error message and ask for a non-empty String.  Return the
    // String to the calling program.
    private static String getInputString(Scanner inScanner) {
        String str = "";
        while (str.equals("")){
            System.out.print("Enter a string: ");
            str = inScanner.nextLine();
            if (str.equals("")){
                System.out.println("ERROR - string must not be empty.");
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
        return str;
        // Fill in the body

        // NOTE: Do not declare a Scanner in the body of this method.
    }


    // Given a String return the number of words in the String.  A word is a sequence of 
    // characters with no spaces.  Write this method so that the function call:
    //      int count = getWordCount("The quick brown fox jumped");
    // results in count having a value of 5.  You will call this method from the main method.
    // For this assignment you may assume that
    // words will be separated by exactly one space.
    private static int getWordCount(String input) {

        int i = 0;
        int wordCount = 0;
        while (i < input.length()){
            char pos = input.charAt(i);
            if (pos == ' '){
                wordCount++;
            }
            i++;            
        }
        return wordCount;
        // Fill in the body
    }
private static String getFirstWord(String input)
        // THIS IS THE METHOD I'M WORKING ON
    }
```

Comment: Hint: String has a method called `substring()`.

Comment: find the index of the first white space in the string and use the `substring()` as mentioned above.

Comment: private static String getFirstWord(String input){
  String firstWord = "";
  String str = ""; 
  int d = str.indexOf(' '); 
  if (d > 0) { 
  System.out.println("." + str.substring(0, d) + "."); 
  } else { 
  System.out.println("." + str + "."); 
  }
  return str.substring(0, d);
 }   This is the logic that I had but I'm not sure how to get in back into main and have everything run still..

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your new method

```
return input.split("\\s")[0]; // split returns an array of all the words. you need just the first word
```